# Is there a wiki software with stick notes functionality built in?

Tags: wiki

I am looking for a **wiki software** with **sticky notes** or post note **functionality** built in.

I come across Zim, but it didn't support post note functionality. 
So ever time , i need to capture notes from **7-notes** and need **manually port** them to **wiki software**.

Kindly put your thoughts if you come across any such software

Answer (score 0):

I know that is possible enable "sticky notes" on PmWiki. [Here](http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/Cookbook/ColorNotes) the post.

The others Wiki have plugin. For example: BoltWire(http://www.boltwire.com/extend/plugins/stickynotes)